# Automatical refactor in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, refactoring

I use NetBeans. I need to refactor my code, because it is very messy. I want to sort fields in files, place brackets equally,  etc. Can I do it automatically in NetBeans? I can't find such an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=netbeans+source+format and many related links.
For the future - try to do some research yourself first.